# 3 divs layout having the middle one fluid

Tags: css

How to achieve the following with CSS?

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  DIV 1: 50px  |  DIV 2: FLUID  |  DIV 3: 50px  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I don't have an issue with a 2 columns layout having the right div fluid, but i can't figure out  how to make the above.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SKsmJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="float:right;width:50px;"></div>
<div style="float:left;width:50px;"></div>
<div style="margin:0 55px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the nicest solution, but you could use nested divs, set the main div's width to whatever you want for your page's width and position the other two with `float`.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
    main
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: block;
}
#main {
    width: 100%;
}
#left, #right {
    width: 50px;
}
#left {
    float: left;
}
#right {
    float: right;
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/davehauser/6qVwR/

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to float both the right and left div, making sure you're right div is the first in the HTML.

I edited the jsfiddle you provided : http://jsfiddle.net/AsKGL/

Answer (score -1):

You just need to `float: left` all `div`s, specifying `width:50px` for the first and last `div`.

Here's a super basic jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Simo990/V3PtW/1